# File entire vector by a certain appearance of another vector

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data:

```
players<-rep(1:3,each=3)
trial<-rep(1:3)
choice<-c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0)
gamematrix<-data.frame(cbind(players,trial,choice))

  players trial choice
1       1     1      1
2       1     2      0
3       1     3      0
4       2     1      0
5       2     2      0
6       2     3      0
7       3     1      0
8       3     2      1
9       3     3      0
```

Now I want to create a new vector:
for *each* participant who have at least one choice of "1", to get the value "3" and "0" otherwise:

```
  players trial choice win
1       1     1      1   3
2       1     2      0   3
3       1     3      0   3
4       2     1      0   0
5       2     2      0   0
6       2     3      0   0
7       3     1      0   3
8       3     2      1   3
9       3     3      0   3
```

In the simple example above, player "1", had "1" in the first trial, while player 3 in the second trial, thus for all their choices the value is "3" in the new vector.

Any ideas how to do it? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base R option using `ave` + `ifelse`

```
within(
  gamematrix,
  win <- ave(choice,players,FUN = function(x) ifelse(any(x==1),3,0))
)
```

giving

```
  players trial choice win
1       1     1      1   3
2       1     2      0   3
3       1     3      0   3
4       2     1      0   0
5       2     2      0   0
6       2     3      0   0
7       3     1      0   3
8       3     2      1   3
9       3     3      0   3
```

---

**Update**

If you criteria is depending on the first two values of `choice`, you can try

```
within(
  gamematrix,
  win <- ave(choice,players,FUN = function(x) ifelse(all(head(x,2)==1),3,0))
)
```

which gives

```
  players trial choice win
1       1     1      1   0
2       1     2      0   0
3       1     3      0   0
4       2     1      0   0
5       2     2      0   0
6       2     3      0   0
7       3     1      0   0
8       3     2      1   0
9       3     3      0   0
```

Comment: Thanks @ThomasIsCoding And how will the answer change if instead of any, I would like it to be only for those players who had "choice=1" in the first N (e.g., first 2 trials)?

Comment: Thanks @ThomasIsCoding, but I wanted it to be 1,1,1 for player1 & player 3 (because for both of them choice =1 within first 2 trials)..

Comment: @YefR Then you should replace `all` by `any`

Answer (score 2):

Try this `dplyr` approach:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
gamematrix <- gamematrix %>% group_by(players) %>%
  mutate(win=ifelse(length(choice[choice==1])>=1,3,0))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   players [3]
  players trial choice   win
    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1       1     1      1     3
2       1     2      0     3
3       1     3      0     3
4       2     1      0     0
5       2     2      0     0
6       2     3      0     0
7       3     1      0     3
8       3     2      1     3
9       3     3      0     3
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason for this data to be a data.frame. Keep it as a numeric matrix. If you do so you can do in one line using only vectorized functions.

```
cbind(gamematrix, win = (rowSums(gamematrix == 1) > 0) * 3)
```

for your second case:

> I would like it to be only for those players who had "choice=1" in the first N (e.g., first 2 trials)

```
cbind(gamematrix, win = (rowSums(gamematrix[,c(1,2)] == 1) > 0) * 3)
```

Vectorized solutions are usually more performant than solutions incorporating a buried loop (e.g. `ave`).

Answer (score 0):

An option with `rowsum` from `base R`

```
gamematrix$win <- with(gamematrix, 3 * players %in% 
           names(which(rowsum(choice, players)[,1] > 0)))
gamematrix$win
#[1] 3 3 3 0 0 0 3 3 3
```